# Creating checkboxlist with a list box

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an requirement to create a list type structure and that will be the options kind of thing.So, when user check the checkboxes or in other words select the options, I have an box equally opposite to it which will show the seleceted options. for eg

The first box contains this::

checkbox      Investemnt-1102
checkbox      credit-rt11
checkbox      debit -2390

the seocond box will list all the items that are selected from first box

as I am new to MVC, I am confused for the first thing that I am not using any third party control.I need to do it custom .so, How can I make it possible. Please suggest.

Comment: Did you look at the CheckBoxList in toolbox ?? Is this you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can always create custom Helpher extended controls in MVC. This is the beauty of MVC.

Do you want something like this?
[MvcCheckBoxList](https://github.com/mikhail-tsennykh/MvcCheckBoxList)

You can play around with your logics easily.

Here is the detailed description of above extension
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292050/CheckBoxList-For-A-missing-MVC-extension

Do google and read about Extensions

Comment: you are right. I need a checkboxlist type of thing but with that I have to show the selected options in another box. The moment user checks a checkbox from the checkboxlist, the option corresponding to that checkbox, should show in another box and so on.

Comment: Sure, you can play with logics around it, download the extension and you can customize it easily, this is how you will learn.